# select distinct (extract(year from saledate) || extract(month from saledate)) as ym from trnsact order by ym;

Tags: mysql, extract, teradata

Working on an exercise question 'How many distinct dates are there in the saledate column of the transaction table for each month/year combination in the database?'  I found a query that works and it is obviously combining the YEAR and MONTH

```
SELECT DISTINCT (extract(year from saledate) || extract(month from saledate)) as SaleDate
FROM trnsact
ORDER BY SaleDate;
```

But the || is not something we have learned and I cannot find syntax, description or examples anywhere. Can someone please explain?

Comment: As you said, it just concatenates multiple values into a single value. You could remove it and use a comma instead to have 2 fields.

Comment: It's not part of MySQL syntax, that's why. It belongs to another dialect. Also, note that DISTINCT is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The || is the string concatenation command. In this query you are giving us, the numbers are converted into string and after that, concatenated.

The solution is valid, I'm afraid.

Another solution would be:

```
select extract( year from saledate) as year_num, 
       extract( month from saledate) as month_num
  from trnsact
group by extract( year from saledate ), 
         extract( month from saledate);
```

Comment: Thank you!  Had to change as year to year_num and month to month_num since I can't use year and month as keywords but it works and I understand how that query is working!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT saledate from trnsact group by YEAR(saledate), MONTH(saledate);
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone taking the same course I am, to find the day counts per month/year combination as they say we should see in the query results:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR from saledate) as year_num, EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate) as month_num, COUNT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY from saledate)) as day_ct
FROM trnsact
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR from saledate), EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate)
ORDER BY year_num, month_num;
```

Answer (score 0):

I also think we need this query.

`SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR from saledate) as year_num, EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate) as month_num, COUNT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY from saledate)) as day_ct FROM trnsact GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR from saledate), EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate) ORDER BY year_num, month_num;`

But not sure if it works. Have you tried that it works

Answer (score 0):

This really bugs me in that Duke online course which I think you are also in. Recentyl I found in the forum that replied by Chris Dunley Mentor:

You can't assume that the format of the joined year month is '2005 8'. This is a common mistake. I prefer simply to exclude all data after 31 July 2005 but you can also use AND/ OR tests. If you want to use the joined text you can do

WHERE YEAR_MONTH<>'EXTRACT(YEAR from '2005-08-01')||EXTRACT(MONTH from '2005-08-01')

Chris"